# The way to access sdcard files without relation to file name in Android application

Tags: android, file

Are there any ways to access a specific file even after a user changes it's file name manually?

Giving a concrete example, my device has a file at "/mnt/sdcard/myfile.png", and my application now accesses this file by indicating the absolute path of the file (which is "/mny/sdcard/myfile.png"). However, this fails if the user changes the name of the file. I want to get files through constant identifier that doesn't change after the file name modification.

Answer (score 2):

No. I don't think there is any **unique** identification of file is available. Just like in DOS (Disk Operation System) and Windows they uses FAT and NTFS to know each item's unique information of the media (HDD).

But i dont this you can access this kind of internal resource through code. So there is no other way to access file without the filename it self.

The alternate way to your requirement is ( i believe your file is not that too big ).

- Put a copy of your file in one folder called `backup`.
- Create an Android Service which will look for your file at original location on every regular interval.
- For regular interval you can use AlarmManager class.
- if Service didnt found the file at original location ( say file is deleted or rename ), then this service will copy the file from `backup` folder and paste it on original folder.

However this logic should be the last option to implement, but the good part is that it fulfil your requirement 100%.

Comment: Ok, I'll manage not to let user change file name. Thank you for your advise!

Comment: @Ryo, I just thought something, there is an alternate way for your requirement. I will let you know by evening. :)

Comment: I was wondering if it's possible to use i-node number.
Thank you very much for your kindness!!!

Comment: In common filesystems the path of a file is its unique identifier :)

Comment: @stoilkov, i know that part, but what i am saying is it is hard to retrieve that unique number.

Comment: @Lucifer what i am saying is: in common file systems there is no such thing as an unique number. there is only the path. there might be filesystems around that let you put custom identifier for a file and keep it when the file is renamed or moved, but i haven't seen this feature in any common filesystem. Plus, Android can be run on many different filesystems, so a solution for the problem at hand would be to monitor file operations on OS level, which i doubt is a desirable solution in this case :)

Comment: @stoilkov opps, my bad, english is my third language :(

Comment: Thank you very much everyone. I'll consider everything that you suggested. I really appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

You can get all images from sdcard.

```
        Cursor cur = this.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,null);  
        startManagingCursor(cur);  
        cur.moveToFirst();
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String str = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME));
            Log.e("#########",str);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I want to access specific file, not all!